# How to programmatically set the system volume?

Tags: c#, .net, audio

How can I change the Windows System Sound Volume using a C# Application?

Comment: Why did you remove the link for the duplicate? The Core Audio API's (Which control the mixer) don't just adjust single programs volumes, it is how you adjust the system volume too. Go actually read the answers in the duplicate and follow their links to the various MSDN articles.

Comment: But the answers in the duplicate do not provide the simplest solutions. Instead it suggests to use unneccessary libraries. Since my specific problem can easily be solved with built-in methods this is not a duplicate of the question linked as duplicate(Though it's pretty similar).

Answer (score 91, accepted):

I'm a bit late to the party but if you are looking now there's a nuget package available ([AudioSwitcher.AudioApi.CoreAudio](https://www.nuget.org/packages/AudioSwitcher.AudioApi.CoreAudio/)) that simplifies audio interactions. Install it then it’s as simple as:

```
CoreAudioDevice defaultPlaybackDevice = new CoreAudioController().DefaultPlaybackDevice;
Debug.WriteLine("Current Volume:" + defaultPlaybackDevice.Volume);
defaultPlaybackDevice.Volume = 80;
```

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/nl-nl/nuget/ - Can you please tell a little more about the Nuget Steps and which exact package?

Comment: The exact package is mentioned above (AudioSwitcher.AudioApi.CoreAudio). So, in the Package Manager Console its "Install-Package AudioSwitcher.AudioApi.CoreAudio". More details at https://www.nuget.org/packages/AudioSwitcher.AudioApi.CoreAudio/

Comment: For some reason, if I get a continuous loop of `A first chance exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in AudioSwitcher.AudioApi.CoreAudio.dll` when I use this method. It's not stopping it from working but is there a way to eliminate this exception?

Comment: Best solution of all. Works flawlessly for my Console Application

Comment: can not use with .NET Core.

Comment: this should be the accepted solution, not those "scripting the gui", autoit-like thing...

Comment: AudioSwitcher.AudioApi.CoreAudio.dll is an abandoned buggy mess

Comment: Why does it take so long to new up theCoreAudioController()

Comment: Note this solution will require you to carry around DLLs or do some tricks to embed them.

Comment: This package is for Visual Studio, right? Is there any for SharpDevelop?

Answer (score 57):

Here is the code:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace Test
{
    public class Test
    {
        private const int APPCOMMAND_VOLUME_MUTE = 0x80000;
        private const int APPCOMMAND_VOLUME_UP = 0xA0000;
        private const int APPCOMMAND_VOLUME_DOWN = 0x90000;
        private const int WM_APPCOMMAND = 0x319;

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        public static extern IntPtr SendMessageW(IntPtr hWnd, int Msg,
            IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

        private void Mute()
        {
            SendMessageW(this.Handle, WM_APPCOMMAND, this.Handle,
                (IntPtr)APPCOMMAND_VOLUME_MUTE);
        }

        private void VolDown()
        {
            SendMessageW(this.Handle, WM_APPCOMMAND, this.Handle,
                (IntPtr)APPCOMMAND_VOLUME_DOWN);
        }

        private void VolUp()
        {
            SendMessageW(this.Handle, WM_APPCOMMAND, this.Handle,
                (IntPtr)APPCOMMAND_VOLUME_UP);
        }
    }
}
```

Found on [dotnetcurry](https://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=431)

When using WPF you need to use `new WindowInteropHelper(this).Handle` instead of `this.Handle` *(thanks Alex Beals)*

Comment: I am trying to use this code in WPF app using C# , I am facing referencing problem at SendMessageW(this.Handle, WM_APPCOMMAND, this.Handle,
                (IntPtr)APPCOMMAND_VOLUME_MUTE); --- This.handle is not available in WPF . can u check ?

Comment: Maybe you could try to use the answer below. It shouldn't interfere with the limitations of WPF. (Or work with WinForms. It may be older but still a lot better (imho))

Comment: Instead of `this.Handle`, use `new WindowInteropHelper(this).Handle`.

Comment: Why is it not working for me in my WinForms app? Do I missed anything?

Comment: Our WinForms app runs on a PC with Windows Explorer not running. This doesn't work without Windows Explorer running. I don't yet know a workaround.

Answer (score 17):

If the tutorials provided in the other answers are too involved you could try an implementation like this using the [keybd_event function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646304%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern void keybd_event(byte bVk, byte bScan, uint dwFlags, int dwExtraInfo);
```

**Usage:**

```
keybd_event((byte)Keys.VolumeUp, 0, 0, 0); // increase volume
keybd_event((byte)Keys.VolumeDown, 0, 0, 0); // decrease volume
```

Comment: But how to set the volume to 50%?

Comment: It doesn't get much simpler than this, Might note that System.Windows.Forms is needed for the "keys" enum, but not required for the command.
voldown = 174, volup = 175, volmute = 173

Comment: @CasterTroy. This works great for simpler use cases without Windows Forms. And this approach provides zero dependency for any nuget packages. Spent hours for studying and trying other approaches and came back to this one. Kudos! And great thanks for this super smart solution!

Comment: And it appears it is compatible back to Windows 2000. I had to google for this version. It was post Win 98 version and one version before Win XP. Unlike alternative audio control implementations this is nice compatibility feature for home users who are still using Win XP.

Answer (score 15):

In case you wish to set it to an exact value using the Core Audio APIs:

```
using CoreAudioApi;

public class SystemVolumeConfigurator
{
        private readonly MMDeviceEnumerator _deviceEnumerator = new MMDeviceEnumerator();
        private readonly MMDevice _playbackDevice;

        public SystemVolumeConfigurator()
        {
            _playbackDevice = _deviceEnumerator.GetDefaultAudioEndpoint(EDataFlow.eRender, ERole.eMultimedia);
        }

        public int GetVolume()
        {
            return (int)(_playbackDevice.AudioEndpointVolume.MasterVolumeLevelScalar * 100);
        }

        public void SetVolume(int volumeLevel)
        {
            if (volumeLevel < 0 || volumeLevel > 100)
                throw new ArgumentException("Volume must be between 0 and 100!");

            _playbackDevice.AudioEndpointVolume.MasterVolumeLevelScalar = volumeLevel / 100.0f;
        }
}
```

Comment: https://whenimbored.xfx.net/2011/01/core-audio-for-net/ Here is a download for the api

Comment: For anyone trying to find this API, they moved to GitHub https://github.com/filoe/cscore and as of this comment, reference `using CSCore.CoreAudioAPI;`

Comment: @SimpleSandman They've updated the API again....  I just looked at the associated tests for up to date examples:   https://github.com/filoe/cscore/blob/master/CSCore.Test/CoreAudioAPI/EndpointTests.cs

Comment: Our WinForms app runs on a PC with Windows Explorer shut down. For us, both APPCOMMAND messages and keyboard emulation don't work. But this works!

Comment: What is `EDataFlow` and `ERole` exactly?

Comment: @Koenigsberg see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/mmdeviceapi/ne-mmdeviceapi-edataflow and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/mmdeviceapi/ne-mmdeviceapi-erole

Comment: I did before coming here, however remained unclear on the `using` etc.

Answer (score 2):

C# code:

```
[Guid("5CDF2C82-841E-4546-9722-0CF74078229A"), InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
interface IAudioEndpointVolume
{
    int _0(); int _1(); int _2(); int _3();
    int SetMasterVolumeLevelScalar(float fLevel, Guid pguidEventContext);
    int _5();
    int GetMasterVolumeLevelScalar(out float pfLevel);
    int _7(); int _8(); int _9(); int _10(); int _11(); int _12();
}

[Guid("D666063F-1587-4E43-81F1-B948E807363F"), InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
interface IMMDevice
{
    int Activate(ref System.Guid id, int clsCtx, int activationParams, out IAudioEndpointVolume aev);
}

[Guid("A95664D2-9614-4F35-A746-DE8DB63617E6"), InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
interface IMMDeviceEnumerator
{
    int _0();
    int GetDefaultAudioEndpoint(int dataFlow, int role, out IMMDevice endpoint);
}

[ComImport, Guid("BCDE0395-E52F-467C-8E3D-C4579291692E")] class MMDeviceEnumeratorComObject { }

public class Audio
{
    private static readonly IAudioEndpointVolume _MMVolume;

    static Audio()
    {
        var enumerator = new MMDeviceEnumeratorComObject() as IMMDeviceEnumerator;
        enumerator.GetDefaultAudioEndpoint(0, 1, out IMMDevice dev);
        var aevGuid = typeof(IAudioEndpointVolume).GUID;
        dev.Activate(ref aevGuid, 1, 0, out _MMVolume);
    }

    public static int Volume
    {
        get
        {
            _MMVolume.GetMasterVolumeLevelScalar(out float level);
            return (int)(level * 100);
        }
        set
        {
            _MMVolume.SetMasterVolumeLevelScalar((float)value / 100, default);
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
Audio.Volume = 50;
```

More info on [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/mmdeviceapi/).

Answer (score 1):

You can add this library https://gist.github.com/sverrirs/d099b34b7f72bb4fb386 to your project and change the volume like this;

```
VideoPlayerController.AudioManager.SetMasterVolume(100);
```

The library also includes options for changing application volume, mute, getting current volume level etc.
The namespace is called "Video Player Controller" but I used it in a Windows Forms App to change the system volume and it worked fine, so the "video" part is arbitrary.

Comment: I found this answer the most helpful because it sets the current device volume, not just the default device volume.  This means you can switch playback devices and still have volume control without taking any additional steps. Certainly, setting the current device volume is also possible using CoreAudio directly, but you must take extra steps to find the current playback device.  At the end of the day, this solution uses CoreAudio like the others, but wraps it in a pretty convenient package, all enclosed in a single file. Clear and concise.

Answer (score 0):

My code is a bit different but still using CoreAudio

downloaded the pkg :
nuget install AudioSwitcher.AudioApi.CoreAudio -Version 3.0.0.1

```
using AudioSwitcher.AudioApi.CoreAudio;
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
public MainWindow()
{

InitializeComponent();

CoreAudioDevice defaultPlaybackDevice = new CoreAudioController().DefaultPlaybackDevice;

double vol = defaultPlaybackDevice.Volume;

defaultPlaybackDevice.Volume = defaultPlaybackDevice.Volume - 5.0;

defaultPlaybackDevice.Volume = defaultPlaybackDevice.Volume + 5.0;
}
}
```

Comment: Why is this library so slow?