# Why can I not change volume in my code?

Tags: c#, .net, audio

I am trying to change the volume on a PC programatically but I am getting no results with this code, I followed another answer on here ([How to programmatically set the system volume?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13139181/how-to-programmatically-set-the-system-volume)) to do this. There are no errors but nothing happens when I call the function, can anyone help?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace UnRestrict.Forms
{

    static class Sounds
    {
        //hexidecimal values for the values needed
        private const int VOLUP = 0xA0000;
        private const int VOLDOWN = 0x90000;
        private const int VOLMUTE = 0x80000;
        private const int APPCMND = 0x319;

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        public static extern IntPtr SendMessageW(IntPtr hWnd, int msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

        public static void VolumeUp()
        {
            SendMessageW(IntPtr.Zero, APPCMND, IntPtr.Zero, (IntPtr) VOLUP);
        }

        public static void VolumeDown()
        {
            SendMessageW(IntPtr.Zero, APPCMND, IntPtr.Zero, (IntPtr)VOLDOWN);
        }

        public static void VolumeMute()
        {
            SendMessageW(IntPtr.Zero, APPCMND, IntPtr.Zero, (IntPtr)VOLMUTE);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: How do you know there are no errors when you're not checking the return value?

Comment: How would I do that? I read IntPtr is just a pointer-like object so how would I check if there was an error?

Comment: Win32 has a habit of overloading return types. The return-type from `SendMessage` has the same width as a native pointer (so you use `IntPtr`) however it does not mean that the value itself is a pointer. You should cast the returned `IntPtr` to an int and then compare that to the return value documented on MSDN ( https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646275(v=vs.85).aspx ) which says it returns `TRUE` in the event of success (`TRUE` is a Win32 macro for `1`) so your code should be: `bool ok = (Int32)SendMessageW(...) == 1`. If it fails, call `GetLastError`.

Comment: Brilliant, thanks. As a noob I'd never hag guessed that! I'll give it a shot!

Comment: I am getting 0 when I cast it to an int32... Acording to MSDN that symoblizes the suer pressing a button...

Comment: Where in MSDN does it say that? If the return value is `0` then it means the `SendMessage` operation failed.

Comment: My bad I read it wrong. Ok so it fails to send... Off to google I go!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it, I read somewhere before tempting this that `SendMessageW()` does nothing with the `hwnd` and `wParam` parameters and you can pass it a null pointer `(IntPtr.Zero)` without issues. This was where I was wrong. I chnaged the IntPtr.Zero values to `Process.GetCurrentProcess().Handle` and all is good now!

Weirdly, the vlaue returned is still not '1' but I also read that this can be normal.

Final Code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace UnRestrict.Forms
{

    static class Sounds
    {
        //hexidecimal values for the values needed
        private const int VOLUP = 0xA0000;
        private const int VOLDOWN = 0x90000;
        private const int VOLMUTE = 0x80000;
        private const int APPCMND = 0x319;

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        public static extern IntPtr SendMessageW(IntPtr hWnd, int msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

        public static void VolumeUp()
        {
            int val = (Int32)SendMessageW(Process.GetCurrentProcess().Handle, APPCMND, Process.GetCurrentProcess().Handle, (IntPtr)VOLUP);
        }

        public static void VolumeDown()
        {
            SendMessageW(Process.GetCurrentProcess().Handle, APPCMND, Process.GetCurrentProcess().Handle, (IntPtr)VOLDOWN);
        }

        public static void VolumeMute()
        {
            SendMessageW(Process.GetCurrentProcess().Handle, APPCMND, Process.GetCurrentProcess().Handle, (IntPtr)VOLMUTE);
        }

    }
}
```