# How to set system volume on ENTER keypress in c# console application?

Tags: c#, console-application

I would like to make a console application in which if a certain user types "volume up" and presses the ENTER key then the system volume to go up.

Any ideas?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please post minimum example of what you have tried so far and where you are stuck.

Comment: Your solution can be constructed using answers here from StackOverflow.
Here's how to control the volume using C#: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13139181/how-to-programmatically-set-the-system-volume
How to get user input from the console and act upon it should be already clear to you.

Comment: I don't know how to get input from a textbox, i know how to do the sound, I tried using key enter event and getting the textbox text but that didnt work?

Answer (score 1):

For creating a console application in c#:
[How to: Create a C# Console Application](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0wc2kk78(v=vs.90).aspx)

To read the input text from a console application: [Console.ReadLine Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.readline(v=vs.110).aspx)

To set the system volume programmatically: [Paedow's question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13139181/how-to-programmatically-set-the-system-volume)

Having these links your job is quite easy now. :)