# How do I create a Slider Volume Control for my C# SoundBoard in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, volume

So I've made this SoundBoard as a fun little project in C# Visual Studio.

So far its working flawlessly, The only thing is that I really dont know how to add a volume bar to it & the software sounds are ridiculously loud.

I think I will have to use a trackBar in Visual Studio but I am not quite sure, so im here looking for some advice!
I saw something on here posted not too long ago & that didnt help me at all, it was close but at the same time very different.
What I need basically is that I need to link the buttons to a Volume Bar in wich case I probably need to create the Volume bar & then link it somehow.
Thanks!

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
/// <summary>
/// Version: 1.0
/// Animal SoundBoard
/// Created By Kinzi aka Varga
/// Date 2015-10-29
/// Category: Fun
/// </summary>
namespace WindowsFormsApplication6
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            System.Media.SoundPlayer player = new System.Media.SoundPlayer();
            player.Stream = Properties.Resources.cow;
            player.Play();
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            System.Media.SoundPlayer player = new System.Media.SoundPlayer();
            player.Stream = Properties.Resources.moose;
            player.Play();
        }

        private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            System.Media.SoundPlayer player = new System.Media.SoundPlayer();
            player.Stream = Properties.Resources.cat;
            player.Play();
        }

        private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            System.Media.SoundPlayer player = new System.Media.SoundPlayer();
            player.Stream = Properties.Resources.dog;
            player.Play();
        }

        private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            System.Media.SoundPlayer player = new System.Media.SoundPlayer();
            player.Stream = Properties.Resources.bird;
            player.Play();
        }

        private void button6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            System.Media.SoundPlayer player = new System.Media.SoundPlayer();
            player.Stream = Properties.Resources.tiger;
            player.Play();
        }

        private void button7_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            System.Media.SoundPlayer player = new System.Media.SoundPlayer();
            player.Stream = Properties.Resources.pig;
            player.Play();
        }

        private void button8_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            System.Media.SoundPlayer player = new System.Media.SoundPlayer();
            player.Stream = Properties.Resources.chicken;
            player.Play();
        }

        private void button9_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            System.Media.SoundPlayer player = new System.Media.SoundPlayer();
            player.Stream = Properties.Resources.duck;
            player.Play();
        }

        private void button10_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            System.Media.SoundPlayer player = new System.Media.SoundPlayer();
            player.Stream = Properties.Resources.seagull;
            player.Play();
        }

        private void button11_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            System.Media.SoundPlayer player = new System.Media.SoundPlayer();
            player.Stream = Properties.Resources.farm;
            player.Play();
        }

        private void button12_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            System.Media.SoundPlayer player = new System.Media.SoundPlayer();
            player.Stream = Properties.Resources.wilderness;
            player.Play();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to programmatically set the system volume?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13139181/how-to-programmatically-set-the-system-volume) The only thing I would add to the accepted answer is that the methods should be declared public, not private.

Comment: Thanks but thats not what I was looking for I dont copy & paste thank you, I needed help in the way of showing me the directions to some where where I can read up about this subject.

Comment: Many of the slider/track bars inherit from ScrollBar which makes them fairly imprecise.  You can write your own to add in whatever goodies you want.  Or check CodeProject, there are surely an assortment there.

Comment: @Plutonix So far this has helped me the most, are you saying that I can read up about ScrollBar & maybe go from there?

Comment: It depends on whether your question is about slider type controls or setting the volume (kind of hard to tell).  `I really dont know how to add a volume bar` sounds like you are looking for a control and I was trying to mention a caution about that. A "SoundBoard" sounds rather professional and I am not sure you'd be happy with a scrollbar based slider.

Comment: @HaleyAlisson You may be mistaken about what StackOverflow does, we'll help you fix code (often by directing you to similar questions), but we aren't tutorial writers. Feel free to look at the code provided, nobody said you had to copy/paste, but it gives you an idea on how to manipulate the system volume. `SoundPlayer` does not have any interface to modify the volume, so you have to do it via p/invoke.

Comment: @ron bayer I dont want you to help me specificlly I just needed directions & if someone could provide me with the information needed instead of linking me to a "Tutorial" it wouldnt be a problem.