# Set System Volume Windows 10 in C#

Tags: c#, audio, win-universal-app, volume

i searched like hours, now i ask in this Forum.

### How can I control the System Volume Setting of Windows 10?

Which Libary I need?

I am using Visual Basic 2015 and wanna programm a Windows Universal App with C#.

### The programm should be able to:

- Set Systemvolume to x%
- increase the Systemvolume by x
- decrease the Systemvolume by x
- get the current Systemvolume

I found a similar Question and Answer, but the Answer doesent work.

private void Mute()
        {

```
        SendMessageW(new WindowInteropHelper(this).Handle, WM_APPCOMMAND, new WindowInteropHelper(this).Handle,
            (IntPtr)APPCOMMAND_VOLUME_MUTE);
    }
```

it can't find "WindowInteropHelper". But I implement:

using System;

using System.Windows.Forms;

using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

Comment: Duplicate of [How to programmatically set the system volume?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13139181/how-to-programmatically-set-the-system-volume)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
class VolumeChanger
{
  private const byte VK_VOLUME_MUTE = 0xAD;
  private const byte VK_VOLUME_DOWN = 0xAE;
  private const byte VK_VOLUME_UP = 0xAF;
  private const UInt32 KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY = 0x0001;
  private const UInt32 KEYEVENTF_KEYUP = 0x0002;

  [DllImport("user32.dll")]
  static extern void keybd_event(byte bVk, byte bScan, UInt32 dwFlags, UInt32 dwExtraInfo);

  [DllImport("user32.dll")]
  static extern Byte MapVirtualKey(UInt32 uCode, UInt32 uMapType);

  public static void VolumeUp()
  {
     keybd_event(VK_VOLUME_UP, MapVirtualKey(VK_VOLUME_UP, 0), KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY, 0);
     keybd_event(VK_VOLUME_UP, MapVirtualKey(VK_VOLUME_UP, 0), KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY | KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0);
  }

  public static void VolumeDown()
  {
     keybd_event(VK_VOLUME_DOWN, MapVirtualKey(VK_VOLUME_DOWN, 0), KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY, 0);
     keybd_event(VK_VOLUME_DOWN, MapVirtualKey(VK_VOLUME_DOWN, 0), KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY | KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0);
  }

  public static void Mute()
  {
     keybd_event(VK_VOLUME_MUTE, MapVirtualKey(VK_VOLUME_MUTE, 0), KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY, 0);
     keybd_event(VK_VOLUME_MUTE, MapVirtualKey(VK_VOLUME_MUTE, 0), KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY | KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0);
  }
}
```

Using this, you can mute, and increase or decrease Systemvolume by 2 degree.

I still searching a way to get the current Systemvolume.

Comment: remember that using Mute(), will Mute OR Unmute, depending of the current state of the audio!

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that. Universal apps are sandboxed and can't make global modifications to the system. This includes the system volume.

Comment: Could I use a Script or something else, that solve my Problem?
Could a Universal Windows App interact with "this" Script?

Comment: I don't want to entirely rule it out, but I'm almost certain it's impossible to run a script, as it'd defeat the whole point of having a sandbox

Comment: That said, if a service was running on the machine, you could definitely interact with this service. That may be a way out

Answer (score 0):

I believe there is a way using nircmd.

First download nircmd and attach it to the project:

http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/nircmd.html

Then, call it via cmd:

[Run Command Prompt Commands](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1469764/run-command-prompt-commands)

The commands you want are specified in the nircmd website.

for instance, to change the volume to x% use:

realativePath/nircmd.exe setsysvolume x