# Control windows volume in Lock Down / alternative shell

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-8.1

I have take the example detailed [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13139181/how-to-programmatically-set-the-system-volume) to enable the control of the windows volume from within my WFP app. It works fine under normal conditions.

The app itself will be run while the device (a ruggedized tablet running Win 8.1 IND) is in lockdown mode. Essentially the windows explorer shell is not loaded and our applications become the 'shell', to prevent tinkering / breaking out of our app.

When running in lockdown mode, I cannot control the volume using the method detailed in the link above.

how can this be achieved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok, found the answer. Need to use the Core Audio API.

https://blog.sverrirs.com/2016/02/windows-coreaudio-api-in-c.html