# CoreAudioApi.dll throwing COMException on some computers

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-7, core-audio

I have to add a feature that allows the user to modify the system volume from within the application. For this purpose I have used `CoreAudioApi.dll` as referenced in other questions on this site.

e.g. [How to programmatically set the system volume?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13139181/how-to-programmatically-set-the-system-volume)

I've added a reference to CoreAudioApi.dll

This works fine on my development computer, however, when the application is run on someone else's computer (e.g. the guy testing it), we get the following exceptions:

```
A first chance exception of type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException' occurred in CoreAudioApi.dll
A first chance exception of type 'Autofac.Core.DependencyResolutionException' occurred in Autofac.dll
A first chance exception of type 'Autofac.Core.DependencyResolutionException' occurred in Autofac.dll
A first chance exception of type 'Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation.ActivationException' occurred in Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation.dll
```

Both PCs are running Windows 7, 64 bit.

Any ideas on what might cause this? Does it reference another dll or something which perhaps I happen to have and the other user doesn't?

**Edit**

Just to narrow down where exactly the exception occurs...

```
private readonly MMDeviceEnumerator _deviceEnumerator = new MMDeviceEnumerator();
private readonly MMDevice _playbackDevice;

public SettingsViewModel()
{ 
    // The exception occurs in the following line:
    _playbackDevice = _deviceEnumerator.GetDefaultAudioEndpoint(EDataFlow.eRender, ERole.eMultimedia);
```

The debugger attempts to enter `ServiceLocatorImplBase.cs` (in case that info is any help)

Comment: Is the other user an admin on their machine?

Comment: @BugFinder - I have already asked them to try running as Admin and it makes no difference.

Answer (score 1):

As usual, I spend hours looking at something, post a question, and then it hits me straight afterwards.

The other computer's audio hardware appears to depend on a speaker or headphones being plugged in before it will even enable itself. They weren't. (Since our application doesn't yet have sounds added, he was relying on visually inspecting the *Windows* volume mixer to test it.) When the other user plugged his headphones in, everything was fine.

I can reproduce the issue on my own PC by disabling the audio hardware. Looks like I'll just have to handle this exception and disable the UI control in this case.