# Speaker Volume Control - Without visuals! VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, controls, volume, speaker

I found out a ways change speakers volume but one thing annoys me. Why do I have to see these visuals?

[visuals image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Loyr4.png)

I am using these functions

`SendMessage(Me.Handle, WM_APPCOMMAND, &H30292, APPCOMMAND_VOLUME_DOWN * &H10000)
SendMessage(Me.Handle, WM_APPCOMMAND, &H30292, APPCOMMAND_VOLUME_UP * &H10000)`

Can I get rid off these visuals? Like I want to do it without any message or images.

Comment: See if [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40361942/2278086) answer helps.

Comment: yep, it helps, thanks bro