# Control Windows system volume using JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, activex

Is there a way to control the system volume in JS? I get an input from an arduino that basically is the volume value (Using a physical volume slider or similar).

The javascript file runs locally, through node.js, and I have heard that ActiveX can be used to control the system volume (Since javascript is normally sandboxed inside of the browser).

See below:

[image]

But I can't comprehend how it works, no matter how much research I do. Of course I have checked out the link, but it only confuses me even more.

The link in the picture:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa263499(VS.60).aspx

**What does it mean that we need to create an ActiveX component, and how do I do it, and how do I control the system volume through that ActiveX component?**

Answer (score 0):

ActiveX is fine if you know you are only delivering to IE (not Edge, just IE).

I am unaware of controlling system volume in any way via the browser. You can control the volume of things like HTML5 / tags, that is about it.

Comment: What I originally tried to say in my question was that my script was only running in cmd, so in other words, completely independent of a browser. Still no idea on how to do it?

Comment: Oh, totally possible from a command line, if that application is being run on the client machine of course. ActiveX was primarily meant to work with Microsoft apps (IE, Word, Excel, etc.. ) and while it still can be, it's pretty much been binned. Here is a random link.. http://www.eweek.com/enterprise-apps/microsoft-bids-farewell-to-activex .. with that in mind, you are free to use any language you want. Now, for my sins, I am a C# dev and it wouldn't take more than a couple of lines to create a little command line app to set global volume. Do you code other languages than JS?

Comment: Well, i do understand C++, and I believe c# isn't all that different?

Comment: c++ will easily do it. I should also add that changing the volume progmatically rather than user interaction can be pretty annoying "if done badly".

Comment: By the way, i found out that windows itself provides you with audiostream apis, which basically lets you retrieve volume levels, and set them as well. Just that it is in C. My strongest language is js, so you know..

Comment: Take a look at this link: maybe you understand how to set it all up? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/audioclient/nf-audioclient-ichannelaudiovolume-getallvolumes

Comment: Yeah, it's just which language you prefer to use to access those APIs. For example here is a StackOverflow question that is c# related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13139181/how-to-programmatically-set-the-system-volume

Comment: Ahhh, Ok :) I see I have to freshen up my C# skills back from my Unity days xD. Anyhow, thanks for the help! Greatly appreciated :) But you said that C++ can do the job. So, you mean that I can access the APIs with c++ instead of C#?

Comment: Sorry for the delay in replying but as you probably know once you can code you can code regardless of the language. I don't know, for example Java, but if I needed to I could put together a one liner, compile it and deploy it. Especially with all the hep available on this site! The APIs are Window's APIs so all C# is doing is exposing them, while I don't know for sure I can only imagine those APIs can be exposed within a C++ environment.