# How to set 'Speaker > Mic/Line/Phono-In' volume in C#

Tags: c#

I am currently developing an application which should control an audio input and playback of local mp3 files.

I can control the incoming audio volume manually in Speaker> Properties> Levels> Mic/Line/Phono-In, in this way I can reduce it to 0 and play a local mp3.

Now I need my program in C # to perform this action automatically, basically configure the volume to 0 and 100.

Is there any way to do this in C # or will it be necessary to do a bash or something like that?

In the following image the property "Mic / Line / Phono-In" is shown, this volume is what I need to control.

[image: Speaker Phono-In level]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to programmatically set the system volume?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13139181/how-to-programmatically-set-the-system-volume)

Comment: System volume is the speaker volume, the first property, but no 'Mic/Line/Phono-In'

Comment: Get on NuGet and grab something like "AudioSwitcher Core Audio API".