# Manipulate Windows 10 Audio Volume Settings .NET Core

Tags: .net-core, windows-10

Do you know if there is a possibily of manipulating Windows 10 audio with .net core? 
Or any other way? I mean, i want to develop some code that allows me to manipulate windows 10 audio.

Comment: is this a pre-existing app or new one? you can easily do this with the `AudioSwitcher.AudioApi.CoreAudio` package which targets .net framework. if it's existing, you may be able to use the nuget package `NetCoreAudio`. if it's a new app, just build it using .net framework instead since it sounds like youre only building for windows. more info here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13139181/how-to-programmatically-set-the-system-volume

Comment: thanks, i'll try it and give you some feedback