# dotnet Core Set System Master Audio Volume

Tags: c#, .net-core

I would like to set the master volume of windows with c# in dotnet core.

This question is NOT a duplicate of [How to programmatically set the system volume?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13139181/how-to-programmatically-set-the-system-volume) because all the answers there are very old and don't work nowadays.

I don't want to increase or decrease the volume by tiny steps. Instead i want to set the volume to a fixed value. Something like this node js library would be nice https://github.com/fcannizzaro/win-audio#readme but unfortunatly i have no clue about on how to move the C++ code over so that i could use it in my C# dotnet core solution.

Comment: They aren't old, and they do work. Even for Core Audio, there's a newer project in a new Github repo and an example [that does exactly what you want](https://github.com/filoe/cscore/blob/master/CSCore.Test/CoreAudioAPI/EndpointTests.cs) The difference is that you want this to run in .NET Core, which can't use all Windows APIs directly

Comment: You'll see that CSCore has an [experimental cross-platform branch](https://github.com/filoe/cscore/tree/netstandard)